# BLE Gateway V4 MQTT and problems getting information msgpack.unpackb using python3

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, paho, msgpack

I am trying to use the information coming from the AB BLE Gateway V4 via MQTT server into python3. After unpacking via msgpack.unpack (payload) the devices array seems to be partially messed up:

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import msgpack

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid))

def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
    for d in msgpack.unpackb(msg.payload)[b'devices']:
      print("=============================================")
      # adv type
      print(d)
      print("type:", ord(d[0]))
      print("mac:{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}".format(ord(d[1]), ord(d[2]), ord(d[3]), ord(d[4]), ord(d[5]), ord(d[6])))
      print("rssi:", ord(d[7]) - 256)
      hex_chars = map(hex,map(ord,d))
      del hex_chars[:8]
      print("adv:", hex_chars)

def on_connect(mosq, obj,flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    mqttc.subscribe("/test", 0)
    print("Connected")


mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.connect("mqtt.bconimg.com", 1883, 60)
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

I expect the output like

```
"type: 3
mac:2026698D97F1
rssi: -66"
```

but I am getting output as blow

```
 "Connected with result code 0
Connected
Subscribed: 1
=============================================
b'\x03\x16*)\x82|\xa7\xa7\x1e\xff\x06\x00\x01\t \x02\x1b6.\xe7P\xdf\xe9\xc3\xe6r\xca\x04H\x96!\xc0z~+\xd9\x13\x91?'
=============================================
b'\x037~M(\x83A\xaa\x1e\xff\x06\x00\x01\t \x02L\x90Ps\xb8\x9e\x80\x996Vx\xe3N\\\x1f\x0c\x8eHE\x0eN\xaf\xbd'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ord from this line and you will be good to go.

#### Line to change

```
print("mac:{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}".format(ord(d[1]), ord(d[2]), ord(d[3]), ord(d[4]), ord(d[5]), ord(d[6])))
```